# Quotas or limits of Google Spreadsheets API v 3.0

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am considering using Google Spreadsheets and Google Apps Scripts for our business rules, given that Spreadsheets will make the business rules available and editable to non-technical employees.

My concern is about all the quotas that apply to Google Apps Scripts, as these also might change in the future, and there is no way to upgrade to a "premium" with more liberal quotas.

As a fall-back I am considering using the Google Spreadsheets API, and I assume that there are also quotas on this API, but I cannot find them anywhere. Does anyone know them? Or has anyone hit these quotas?

I am also trying to get some sort of idea of whether it is indeed a good idea to put the business rules in Google Spreadsheets in my question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/251248/complexity-limits-of-solutions-created-in-google-spreadsheets).

Comment: Did you look here?  [Quotas](https://script.google.com/dashboard)

Comment: Yes those quotas are so worrying, especially the Trigger Aggregate Execution Time. This is why I want to check the possibilities of falling back to the Google Spreadsheets API, which enables external software to read and modify the contents of a spreadsheet.

Comment: But if you are going to call the v3 api from gas you will be limiyed by the urlfetch quotas.

Comment: Spreadsheets api v3 is an old api and doesnt (seem to) have quota protection from what Ive experienced. I have an app with thousands of users using that api with the same console keys and the quota charts dont even show my calls in there (and do show calls from other apis like Drive which I use to create spreadsheets.)

Comment: However in my case each user uses their own oauth tokens so quotas might be spreading and not concentrated on a single user, in which case you might have 'rate limit' errors.

Comment: @ZigMandel Yes, I would call it from our Linux server, and I would much prefer to use one Google Account to avoid account management complexity.

Comment: still should work. try it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an Apps Script Dashboard which identifies any service disruptions, as well as a tab for a breakdown of quotas, based on your Google Apps account type.

[Google Apps Script Dashboard](https://docs.google.com/a/macros/onixnet.com/dashboard)

From a quick skim of your posting on StackExchange, one thing to be mindful of is the email quota (1500 total recipients per account each day).  You may be able to offset this hurdle (if applicable) using Google Groups, either by creating predefined groups, or programmatically building groups using Advanced Google service in Apps Script (at least for internal communications; direct add accounts for external addresses require a welcome message).

I'm not familiar with Ultradox, but using Apps Script, you can populate Google Doc "Template" files, convert them to PDF, and attach in Gmail (or provide the share link), right from Apps Script.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about avoiding Ultradox, Ultradox enables the usage of Amazons mail delivery service so it can be useful. The Trigger Aggregate Execution Time and other triggers are is worrying me. This is why I want to check the possibilities of falling back to the Google Spreadsheets API, which enables external software to read and modify the contents of a spreadsheet.

Comment: Along that same token, if your software could deal with JSON or XML, you could use Apps Script ContentService to return a JSON or XML aggregation of your spreadsheet data.  This might also provide you some flexibility, as you could also utilize query parameters in your request for varied responses.